# Find full matches in one field when related to a second field

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I'd be grateful for some help with a problem that I hope to summarise reasonably with the two tables below:

[image]

Table1 contains the primary raw data where FieldA has a relationship with specific items in FieldB.

The items in FieldB are unique with respect to each unique item in FieldA - that is, cat, dog, rabbit, chicken will only ever appear once under the "a" group in FieldA (they can appear elsewhere in the field). Similarly for the b,c and d items in FieldA (all FieldB items only appear once against each).

Table2 lists the total count of each unique item in Table1, FieldB and is generated by the following query:

qryCount:

```
select FieldB, count(FieldB) AS FCount 
from Table1
GROUP BY FieldB;
```

**My problem:**
The user enters unique values from FieldA in Table1 then, the query should return all unique values in FieldB (Table1) where a full match is achieved, with respect to the respective FCount total in Table2.

e.g.

- If the user enters "a,b,d" the query outputs "cat, dog, rabbit, ferret" since the total count for cat(3), dog(2), rabbit(1) and ferret(1) are met.
- If the user enters "a,c" the query outputs "chicken,rabbit" since the total count is met for chicken(2) and rabbit(1).
- If the user enters "b" the query returns nothing since the respective FieldB items are also present elsewhere.

I do have this problem solved using VBA in Excel (building a hit table and seeing if the respective total counts for user-entered values are met), but though I do have some experience in using Access SQL (2007), I'm struggling to convert this idea from VBA. I'd be grateful for some help.

Comment: Surely for `a, b, d` the counts are also met for `rabbit` and `ferret` since there is 1 in both cases?

Comment: Apologies, too late in the night - yes, rabbit and ferret conditions are met. Text updated.

Comment: Likewise for `a,c` it should return `rabbit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want. It uses a subquery to generate an effective copy of `Table2` but only for the desired values of `FieldA`. This is then joined to `Table2`, giving only rows where the values of `FCount` match:

```
SELECT t1.FieldB
FROM (SELECT FieldB, COUNT(FieldB) AS FCount
      FROM Table1
      WHERE FieldA IN ('a', 'b', 'd')
      GROUP BY FieldB) t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.FieldB = t1.FieldB AND t2.FCount = t1.FCount
```

Output:

```
FieldB
cat
dog
ferret
rabbit
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=99d1cb1a76b3a500eec012b4cdf932b1)

Comment: Many thanks for this - and the pointer to dbfiddle...that's very useful. While all works perfectly there, Access SQL (2007) has an issue with the JOIN line ("Error in FROM clause" - query runs with line removed).

Comment: @Jim I think Access might require it to be explicitly `INNER JOIN` - see my edit

Comment: INNER JOIN works perfectly (Access a bit daft at times) - cheers!! I'll now need to carefully look over both these excellent answers, block at a time, and find out how they work. It's nice that there's two different methods. It's a shame that I can't 'accept' both answers.

Comment: @Jim yeah - Access is a law unto itself. I'm glad that solved the problem. As you say, a pity you can't accept two answers, all you can do is upvote both (which I presume you already did).

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood the logic, I would suggest the following:

```
select distinct t1.fieldb from table1 t1 
where 
    t1.fielda in ('a', 'b', 'd') and 
    not exists 
    (
        select 1 from table1 t2 
        where t2.fieldb = t1.fieldb and t2.fielda not in ('a', 'b', 'd')
    )
```

A few notes on the above:

- The query is essentially selecting records for which the value held by `FieldB` only appears in the targeted `FieldA` groups (in this case `a`,`b`,`d`) and in no other groups.
- Only `table1` is referenced by the query, as no aggregation or counting is used.
- The use of `select 1` is purely an optimisation, since we don't care what the correlated subquery returns, but only that one or more records exist - as such, it can return the minimum amount of information necessary to verify this.

Comment: Many thanks for this excellent answer - all working perfectly. I'll now need to look over both answers slowly and find out how they work (good that they're different). I wish I could 'accept' both answers - daft that you can't.

Comment: Thanks @Jim. FWIW, I've updated my answer above to provide more of an explanation as to how the query operates.